# PHP: Form variables not registering

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an HTML form for a limo company's info, kind of like this:

```
<td>
     <input type="text" name="sedan-number-fleet" />
</td>
<td>
     <input type="text" name="sedan-year-range" />
</td>
```

and so on. When I put them into PHP, like so:

```
$input_sedan_number_fleet = strip_tags($POST['sedan-number-fleet']);
$input_sedan_year_range = strip_tags($POST['sedan-year-range']);
```

it comes out with no result when I try to echo it. Does it have to do with the `strip_tags` function? If you know, let me know. That would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't access form-submitted data through `$POST`, but `$_POST`. Change your code to

```
$input_sedan_number_fleet = strip_tags($_POST['sedan-number-fleet']);
$input_sedan_year_range = strip_tags($_POST['sedan-year-range']);
```

And also, I hope you do more input validation than just `strip_tags`.

Comment: When you run into issues like these, start out by limiting the problems scope and locating the cause.  First, I'd do a `print_r($POST)` then realize that `$POST` doesn't exist at which point you should confront the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). :)

Answer (score 1):

replace `$POST` with `$_POST`. This should do the job. Additionally, use `$_GET` instead of `$GET` and so on (read more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php))

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with this too. Try using " instead of '.

For example:

```
$input_sedan_number_fleet = strip_tags($_POST["sedan-number-fleet"]);
$input_sedan_year_range = strip_tags($_POST["sedan-year-range"]);
```

For some reason that worked for me.